# Rails Nested Resource Scoped to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app, websites have many pages. I'm trying to setup my URLs to look like

```
example.com/websites/1/pagename
```

I want it so page names don't need to be globally unique. They just need to be unique within the website they belong to.

This is what my routes look like so far

```
resources :websites do
    resources :pages, :path => ''
end
```

---

### UPDATE

I got it working by changing this line in the pages controller.

```
def show
    @page = Page.find_by(website_id: params[:website_id], id: params[:id])
end
```

However, then I updated that line to use Friendly ID...

```
def show
    @page = Page.friendly.find_by(website_id: params[:website_id], id: params[:id])
end
```

Now I get an error `undefined method name for nil:NilClass` because I have `<% provide(:title, @page.name) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You don't need.

The `rails g controller websites/pages` to use with namespace.

Your URL: `websites/1` the `id = 1` is unique. and the `pagename` also unique for each website

=> `websites/1/pagename` is unique

It's fine for:

```
websites/1/page_about_author
```

and

```
websites/2/page_about_author
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem I'm having is, when I visit /websites/2/page_about_author or /websites/3/page_about_author it is displaying the content for /websites/1/page_about_author. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: To display name of page on url. Are you using friendly_id?

Comment: Yep, I am...is that an issue? Or do I just not have it configured correctly?

Comment: I tried removing Friendly ID from the pages controller and visited websites/3/page_id but it still shows websites/1/page_id

Comment: I got it. Problem is on controller `page`,  action `show`. You are finding `page` by id, right? Maybe your code is `@page = Page.find(params[:id])` Change it to `@website = Website.find(params[:website_id])` and new line `@page=@website.pages.find(params[:id])`

Comment: or more simple. Just `@page = Page.find_by(website_id: params[website_id], id: params[:id])`

Comment: So with the first solution you posted in the comments, I get this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/paeo5d7gbemenpr/Screenshot%202016-12-09%2004.42.27.png?dl=0

Comment: With this second, simpler solution, I get this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/gk25k2kzs0sorjz/Screenshot%202016-12-09%2004.43.13.png?dl=0

Comment: Both are worked. The reason here is. For ex: page1 title is `page_author_about` belongs to website1, page2 title the same and blongs to webiste2. If you call by id. It must be `websites/1/1` and `websites/2/2`, but in case of using friendly_url, 2 urls changed to `websites/1/page_author_about` and `websites/2/page_author_about`. And on your controller, edit for corresponding

Comment: The errors because, you enter link websites/1/2, the page2 is not belong to website1 => show error can't file with id...

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I have it working now except for with Friendly ID

Comment: Try that
`Page.where(website_id: params[:website_id]).friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: That gives me the following error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound https://www.dropbox.com/s/45dtmxl65kj8tnu/Screenshot%202016-12-09%2006.07.38.png?dl=0

Comment: I think now, it's easy. Just debug it. `Page.where(website_id: params[:website_id])` Please make sure you have a page 'homepage' belongs to websites2